# Install Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After downloading and installing Visual Studio 2012, I cannot launch it and keep on receiving error -- Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I cannot even get into the application. The VS2012 just can't launch. Is there anyway out? I have posted the question on Microsoft forum. But the answers are not very helpful or have been tried.

This question has been bothering me for few months.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I just had the same thing happen with a Fresh install of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: no. I need a fresh install. But most probably you missed a C++ Redistributables or sth.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking and running as administrator?

Comment: Would you please tell me what details do u need?
There seems to be no way out. The exception box just pops up every time I launch VS2012 and then it just shuts itself down.
Does anyone have this experience regarding this VS2012?

Comment: Is there anything else in the exception box? Does it give an inner exception or a stack trace?

Comment: Run Windows Update and check for any updates for Visual Studio, especially any service packs or other major updates.

Comment: Sorry. Not much progress. In fact I have updated windows before installing, as recommended by VS2012 forum. I have also applied SP update.